# Which method replaced 'GetSearchResults' in eBay API?

Tags: ebay-api

I'm reading "Programming Collective Intelligence" and the example in the 8th chapter was using eBay API, but it doesn't work when I use the method `GetSearchResults`.

I've been reading the eBay API documentation and found that the method `GetSearchResults` used to be in eBay Trading API. But I can't find which method replaced it.

Answer (score 1):

The Trading API call "GetSearchResults" was deprecated a few years ago, along with some other eBay API calls that similarly searched eBay. The new replacement API calls are in the Finding API family, and are REST-based calls instead of token-based calls that need to be POST'd (the latter still being true for the rest of the current Trading API calls).

You'll probably want to use the call 'findItemsAdvanced' in the Finding API. See these 2 docs pages for more info:

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/Concepts/map_GetSearchResults_2_FindingService.html

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [ebay SDK](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python) library to support your work if you use Python.

A simple:

```
from ebaysdk import trading
api = trading(appid="YOUR_APPID", devid="YOUR_DEVID", 
              certid="YOUR_CERTID", token="YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN")
api.execute('GetUser', {})
print api.response_dict()
```

Or you can use `urllib` to implement by yourself.